# Negative lookbehind regex (PERL) with variable characters in-between

Tags: regex, perl, negative-lookbehind

I'm having a problem with a negative lookbehind regex. I've read the stackoverflow results and I'm afraid I don't quite understand them.

I operate a game server, and I have a tool that reads the users' chat and kicks a user if they use a banned word. The tool uses the PERL regex engine.

Say my banned words are popular derivations of "bag" or "digger". I can use the following regex to match chat lines containing these words.

```
(?i)(digg|bag)(?-i)
```

There are other words in my actual list.

However, I like to offer a warning first, which appears in chat as:

> Owner: Don't say "digger"

So I've tried using a negative lookbehind to avoid matching my banned words list when it is preceded by "Owner:" - however, I can only get it to work if I specify the exact text I use between ":" and the banned word - which I don't always do, and frequently accidentally match my self.

I've tried to use:

```
(?<!Owner\:)/s*(?i)(digg|bag)(?-i)
```

which works if there's only whitespace, but what I really want is to not match:

> Owner:digger
>
> Owner: Digger
>
> Owner: don't use bag as an insult
>
> Owner:(anything else here)dig

*et cetera*, but match:

> (anything else):(any banned word regardless of what precedes it after the colon)

I can't work out if what I want is even possible in this syntax, because of zero-width assertions (which I can't wrap my head around), or if my regex-fu is just weak.

I've tried a couple of tutorials, and using the regex101 parser, but I can't quite get what I want. Please can you help?

Comment: Not so hard. Is the colon always going to be there ? Single line, multiple lines, etc ??

Comment: Hello! The chat is a concatenation of the user's name, a colon, a space (I think) and what ever they've said. As far as I am aware, it's all on one line (I tried to work something out with "line starts with Owner:" but had a similar problem). I think it's specifying an indeterminate number of characters and spaces between my lookbehind and my match string that's tripping me up. Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Can I suggest the answer is don't try and single-regex it, but just match `Owner:` and 'allow' that.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you just want:

```
/^(?!Owner:).*(?i:(digg|bag))/s
```

Matching messages that don't start with Owner: and contain (case insensitive) digg or bag.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `(?<!Owner):[^:]*?\K(?i:digg|bag)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pP9eK0/1)

Explanation

```
 (?<! Owner )                  # Not 'Owner' behind colon
 : [^:]*?                      # Colon, then not Colon's up to the ..
 \K                            # Previous, not part of match
 (?i: digg | bag )             # Only the bad word will match $&
```

If you expect it to be line oriented where the check for `Owner` is at/close
to the beginning, use this:

Using captured parts.

`(?mi)^(?!\h*Owner:)\h*([^:\r\n]*?):(.*?)(digg|bag)`

Expanded

```
 (?mi)
 ^  
 (?! \h* Owner: )
 \h*                           # Trim whitespace
 ( [^:\r\n]*? )                # (1), User
 : 
 ( .*? )                       # (2), Before bad word
 ( digg | bag )                # (3), Bad word
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried to parse some test cases with it [here](http://s24.postimg.org/6f4ug3z79/sln1.jpg) - as you can see the first four lines parse as expected, but the last two should match and do not (blue highlighting indicating a match only in line 4).

Comment: Uh, perhaps you should use the global flag?

Comment: Added a demo, do you need a Perl sample?

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work in regex parser - I'll try it in live later, when the server population is low and mark the answer afterwards. I don't need a Perl demo thanks. I don't quite understand what you're doing between (1) and (2) - would you mind explaining please?

Comment: @RustyRegex - what do you mean by "between (1) and (2)". In the second regex? Or between the first and second regex?

Answer (score 2):

```
Owner\:\s*.*?(digg|bag)(*SKIP)(*F)|(digg|bag)
```

You can use `(*SKIP)(*F)` to fail when `Owner` is there.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE6jQ1/5

Comment: Wouldn't just `Owner:\s+(*SKIP)(*F)|...` be enough in this case?

Comment: I am wrong. I just tested it on the command line and it doesn't work as I thought. So, your regex is correct.